# background position not centering while background-attachment fixed applied?

Tags: html, css, layout, sass

This is what my background currently looks like with the following CSS and background attachement fixed applied

[image: 1]

```
    /* APPLY SECTION */
section.apply {
    height: 55rem;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("../img/apply.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;

}

.apply::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.apply * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.apply .apply-content {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.apply .apply-content h2 {
    max-width: 30rem;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is with background-attachement fixed removed

[image: 2]

How do I add background attachment fixed and be able to center the background using background-position, size, and repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
section.apply {
    height: 55rem;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("../img/apply.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    background-position-y:10px

}
```

try using this

Comment: Thanks! I can work with this. It doesn't quite look like the picture with background attachment fixed removed, but at least this gets the image in frame.